# VBA - How to convert value of cell from text to number

Tags: vba, excel, format, number-formatting

I have to columns with exported numbers, which are stored as text.

[image]

I tried to convert those data to numbers with this code.

```
Sub FormatColumns()
 Columns(9).NumberFormat = "0"
 Columns(10).NumberFormat = "0"
End Sub
```

It has done the job correctly (or it seems so), but I am still not able to work with those data as with numbers, but Excel tell me, that it is stored as number.

[image]

But when I verify it via formula `=ISTEXT()`, it always shows me *TRUE*

Could you help me with it, please? All tutorials and advices, which I've found on Google was via Formating cells or `=VALUE()`, but VALUE fucntion doesnt work for me, it shows me *#VALUE*.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Its the comma, needs to be `.` `405,90` = `405.90`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must replace ","  ~~> "."

```
Sub FormatColumns()
 With Columns("i:j")
    .Replace ",", "."
    .NumberFormat = "#,###.00"
 End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Range("A:A").Select 'Range of values you need converted

    For Each Cell In Selection
    Cell.Value = (Cell.Value * 1)
    Next

End Sub
```

A non-vba equivalent solution is to have a "1" entered in a cell, copy that cell, select the range you would like converted to numbers, right click and press Paste Special -> Multiply.

This will leave all values in that range as numbers without changing the format. Tested with ISTEXT.

Make sure your settings also match with commas replacing decimals otherwise it may continue to have issues.

Answer (score 1):

Check entire relevant region is set to Number format first.

Selection the relevant region and do a global replace of  for nothing ("space" to "leave empty"). Then depending upon your locale try a global replace of `,` to `.`.

Next enter `1` in a spare cell, copy that cell, select the entire relevant region and Paste Special, Option, Multiply.

If that does not work switch `.` back to `,` and repeat the Paste Special.

Answer (score 1):

Its the comma, needs to be `.` so  `405,90` = `405.90`

Answer (score 0):

Converting numbers stored as text to numbers via Macro

```
Sub macro() 
    Range("F:F").Select 'specify the range which suits your purpose
    With Selection 
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General" 
        .Value = .Value 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work at this case. There were space and commas, which had to be correct. But thank you very much for your advice, since it works in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Hilight the numbers you with to "fix" and run:

```
Sub fixNumbers()
    With Selection
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: As I wrote to @Rick's post, it does not work at this case. There were space and commas, which had to be corrected. But thank you very much for your advice, since it works in other cases.